# Notation for universal morphism

Tags: notation, category-theory, tensor-products, universal-property

In my course on von Neumann algebras we have introduced the tensor product and its universal property. We have notated the morphism from the product into the tensor product with a $\hookrightarrow$. I am used to use this symbol for monomorphisms but this is clearly not one.

I did some research and figuered out that this morphism together with its target object is somehow special and is called a universal morphism. Another example for this type of morphism-object-pair can be found in the homomorphism theorem for groups, where we have that for a normal subgroup $N$ the projection onto the quotient $G/N$ is universal for the morphisms $f$ with $\ker f \subseteq N$. (universal here means that the other morphisms factor uniquely through the universal one)

It seems natural to me that one wants to emphasize in a diagram that a morphism is universal. As we did it with the $\hookrightarrow$ seems not as the best option to me. I saw a diagram for the homomorphism theorem on wikipedia but they used a normal arrow symbol. Now my question is: Are there some conventions on the notation of universal morphisms?

Kind regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have not seen any specialized notation for this before. The convention is to use a plain arrow as far as I know.

See "Categories for the Working Mathematician" (MacLane) III.1 or "Handbook of Categorical Algebra I" (Borceux) 3.1 where adjunctions are explained; or virtually any other book dealing with adjunctions (defining the notion of a universal morphism is not so common I guess).

Although in the case of an adjunction the universal morphisms are components of the *unit*, which is commonly denoted by $\eta$.